# Rsync & MergerFS creating directories one by one

Tags: rsync, directory-structure

I have mergerfs setup with the default policy of epmfs. This means if I have `local/target/` on all disks and copy files into `local/target/`, each file will get copied to the disk that has the most free space at the time it is copied.

I want to use `rsync` to transfer files from a remote machine, as in `rsync -rt user@remote:/remote/target/ local/target/`, where the `local/target/` directory is already copied across all disks with no content. If `/remote/target/` is just full of files, this works fine, the individual files are spread evenly across the disks as expected because the next file is only created after the last one has finished transferring. If `/remote/target/` has many subdirectories though, all of the subdirectories are created instantly before any files are transferred. This breaks the intended epmfs behavior, because all of the subdirectories will be created on only one disk instead of spread across the disks like files would be.

Is there any way to force `rsync` to create the subdirectories one by one, just in time before the actual subdirectory content is transferred?

This would mean that by the time the next subdirectory is created, the free space would be lower on the first disk and the next disk could be selected. I have tried a few `rsync` options like `-O` and `--no-i-r` but nothing seems to change this behavior, and nothing else on the manpage seems to point to a way to suppress the directory creation. Alternatively, is there any other way around this problem without affecting the intended behavior of the epmfs policy?

After discussing it with [C.M.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74599/c-m) one option would be to run `rsync` separately for each subdirectory being transferred, but I would rather avoid that if possible. Ideally I want to use a method that can still show overall transfer progress, resume failed transfers, etc.

This is the simplest way I could find to do the multiple `rsync` version, although it only works if `rsync` runs on the sending side rather than the receiving side:

```
find /local/target/ -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'rsync -rt "{}" user@example.com:/remote/target/' \;
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you have done/tried. For example, what is the `rsync` command line you used, etc? (Maybe seeing the code/script we can figure out  if what you really want is to `rcp` instead? And so on.)

Comment: I'm not using anything complicated, the exact command I'm using is "rsync --info=progress2 -rt user@myserver.example.com:/filepool/files/xxxxx /mnt/storage/xxxxx". There is no script involved. It's just copying files from one linux machine to another while preserving file timestamps. If there is another common linux tool that does the same thing but copies the files one by one that is fine for my purposes as long as it preserves file timestamps and doesn't have other major downsides.

Comment: The -t option takes care of the timestamp, so that is not an issue. The issue is with the -r option to recurse directories. Part of recursing directories _implies_ the directory must exist to be recursed. So, `rsync` is seeing that the directory does not exist on the destination, and faithfully does what you told it to do--creating files and directories that do not exist. But what you really want is to create the directory _if and only if it_ is necessary to create it because it contains files that must be copied, but not if there are no files to copy (such as an empty directory). Correct?

Comment: No that's not the issue. Let's say directory Alphabet contains subdirectories A-Z that are 10GB each. If I do a Windows file copy from machine 1 to machine 2, it will create A, then copy the 10GB inside A, then create B, then copy the 10GB inside B, etc. When I use rsync to do the same thing, it instantly creates A-Z, then starts filling A, then filling B, etc. I'm using MergerFS which is why the difference matters. With the Windows file copy, at the time B is created, MergerFS sees that the disk containing A is too big and selects a new drive to hold B. With rsync all content is on one drive.

Comment: Take a step back, and put the MergerFS part aside for now. Pretend you are writing an rsync tool. You encounter a directory to sync, what do you do? You obtain a list of entries within the directory. This list _includes_ the names of sub-directories. You have two choices you can make: Do you process the list you have _right now_ or do you put the list aside and processes each sub-directory first? rsync is doing the first option. It sees that sub-directory-1 does not exist, so it creates it in order to sync it--it has not yet even tried to process what is _in_ sub-directory-1.

Comment: This is why I'm asking you these questions to clarify the problem. Without a clear understanding of the problem, finding a solution is hit or miss. But once you understand the problem--you, myself, or others might see an immediate and obvious solution.

Comment: Yes, it seems like rsync is processing it the way you describe, whereas many other file transfer tools (Windows file copy, lftp, etc.) process the directories one by one. The point of asking this question was to see if there is any way to make rsync have a different set of behavior, since it breaks MergerFS functionality, or alternatively if there is any other way of doing the same thing. It seems like MergerFS is not very popular in general so I can't find a lot of information on how to solve this problem, and I'm not familiar with most of the alternatives to rsync on linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123504/discussion-between-c-m-and-chris-graham).